# traverse nodes in Graph not working perfectly in js

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph

I have created a graph which containing key and value pair ,key is for node number and value for adjacency list value which is an array of adjacent edges, here I wrote a function that will traverse the node and adjacency edges in the graph, but here the function is not working ,which thing should I have to modified here that I want graph traversal using dfs code is given below:

```
 var graph = {
    1: [2, 4],
    2: [1, 3],
    3: [2, 4],
    4: [1, 4]
  };

  function dfs(start, graph) {
    const queue = [start];
    queue.push(start);
    while (queue.length > 0) {
      let vertex = queue.pop();
      for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
        if (!vertex[graph[i]]) {
          dfs(graph[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(graph);
```

Comment: Maybe take some time to give feed back on your previous question? Answering questions is no fun when the asker just walks away without reaction or marking an answer as accepted.

Comment: *"the function is not working"*: what do you expect the code to do? The function `dfs` is not called, so it just sits there. If you would call it, what do you want to happen? Is there some output you expect?

Comment: in that dfs function i want the dfs traversal code ,no that program is not ready yet , so I am not calling this, have you gave some suggestion to modifying that code

Comment: If you can tell us what you expect as **output** or as content of a variable, or ... some way this function is useful, then we can answer the question.

Comment: I expect as that all nodes are visited once and gives output like {1: [2, 4], 2: [1, 3], 3: [2, 4], 4: [1, 4]} when call the function dfs()

Comment: That output is just the initial graph. You don't need to call `dfs` for that. How will you record that a node is visited? How will you **test** a solution and consider it is correct? There must be some output you expect, or there is no use in calling `dfs`...

Comment: only I need to check the traversal of the graph, is there any solution do you have?

Comment: You are not answering my question. I'll move on.

Comment: A minor point: is that your "queue" is not a "queue" but rather a stack. DFS uses stacks, while BFS uses queues. Change the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm doesn't work because you are confusing iteration with recursion. You need to decide whether you want to use a recursive algorithm or an iterative one. Not both.

A basic iterative depth first search works as follows:

0. You'll need a stack (not a queue as in BFS) and a **visited** set. The Visited set is important to ensure you don't get stuck in an infinite loop since graphs may have cycles.
1. Then you add vertex number for the start position into the stack
2. Then while your stack has elements in it
3. pop a vertex off the stack
4. *visit* the element (for example, print it or do whatever processing you want)
5. add the vertex to the **visited** set.
6. then, for each adjacent vertex (go through the list of adjacent elements in the adjacency list), check if it is in the **visited** set, if not then add it to the stack
7. Repeat step 2

Your attempt to this problem confuses the iteration of the adjacent elements with iterating the entire graph and recursively calls DFS again rather than adding the adjacent elements to the stack.

It's also missing the visited set which is critical with graphs with cycles in them.

ps. BFS is exactly the same code but switch in the stack for a queue.